# Migrating JUL to log4j2, performance is not as expected. What went wrong?

Tags: java, performance, log4j2

I am a new user of log4j2. Based on [Log4j2 performance tests](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html) introduction, and it may need to generate a large number of csv files for data processing. I plan to migrate a project from JUL to log4j2. This is a multi-threaded project that uses a lot of loggers. But the test results are not satisfactory . Where did I get it wrong?
[the compare results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YRoT.png)

The dependency configuration is as follows:

```
<!-- Log4j2 api -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log4j2 impl.-->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for Log4j2 asynchronous logging-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency> 
    <!-- for Log4j2 csvlayout-->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

File "log4j2.xml" has multiple similar appenders and loggers, for example:
[partial configuration for log4j2.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HKNe.png)

Java related code is as follows:

```
    System.setProperty("log4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable", "true");
    String renameCsvFile = new String( inputDir.getName() + StaticUtils.SEPARATOR +"log"+ StaticUtils.SEPARATOR + "rename");
    ThreadContext.put("module3", renameCsvFile);
    rename_logger = LogManager.getLogger("myrenamelog");

    rename_logger.info("rename logging", "Timestamp","Level",  "OrignalPath","RenamedPath","Status", "Message", "Layer#", "Thread#");

    rename_logger.info("rename logging...", Instant.now(),"info",file.getAbsolutePath(),newName.getAbsolutePath(),"success"," ","Layer#",Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Comment: Furtherly, I turned off localinformation, turned on asynchronous logger mode by: `System.setProperty ("log4j2.contextSelector", "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");` But performance has not improved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you upgrade to the latest release. Specifically, [LOG4J2-2644](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2644), which was addressed in Log4j 2.12.1, should impact some of your performance times. However, as in [LOG4J2-2792](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4J2/issues/LOG4J2-2792), some applications that rely heavily on filters might need to disable eagerly obtaining the location.

If after testing with a newer version you still have problems please create a Jira issue with Log4j. Ideally you should either provide a sample test suite to demonstrate the problem and/or a snapshot created with a profiling tool such as YourKit that can help identify the problem areas.